# Layers and shadow passes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Render shadows separately，The rendered shadow cannot cover the object.

[image]

Comment: Easier solution than finding solution for this would be use that plane you used for shadows as shadow catcher and render it as object with shadows in one render, why don't you try it like that? Btw it looks like some weird outline, do you have freestyle on? One more question, did you cut it out or rendered it on transparent background?

Comment: Why do you mask shadow?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, so it is hard to advise more specifically for your situation without knowing more context, but when compositing, if you want to control the shadows or change the background you should have:

- The background
- The shadow without the hole for the object
- The object

So you could render the shadows with transparent background and shadow catcher objects or you could give the shadow catching objects completely white color so they catch some color information with the shadow as well but you should just put your shadow casting object into a collection and set it
to Indirect Only mode:

[image]

Then you can composite your new background, the shadow render pass on top in multiply mode, and then only the object on top of that.

[image]